# Android - reading txt files from external jar

Tags: java, android

I have a jar compiled with core jdk.

It contains a java class which reads a txt file.
It has a test which proves that this class works correctly.

If I include this jar in my android project and then call the java class that reads the txt file. It fails reporting: java.io.FileNotFoundException and adding a '/' to the path of the txt file which I wanted to load.

Is Android's security model stopping the txt file from being read?

**My Project structure:**

**Android Module:**

*src/Loader.java [calls GetName.java]*

**Java Module:**

*test/TestGetName.java [calls GetName.java]*

*src/GetName.java*

*resources/names.txt*

**Summary:**

TestGetName.java works

Loader.java fails. A FileNotFoundException is thrown inside GetName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out in the end. I need a condition to see if I am loading the file locally or as a resource. There is probably a neater way to do this without using a conditional.

```
    String source = "resources/inputfile.txt";
    BufferedReader fin;

    InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(source.substring(source.lastIndexOf("/")));
    if (inputStream != null) {
        fin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    } else {
        fin = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(source)));
    }
```

Thanks for the hints about reading as a resource user77777777

Answer (score 1):

It doesnt seem like the Android stopping it from accessing the file because the exception is `FileNotFoundException`. You should check the detailed message to confirm that. Catch the Exception and print the detailed message. That will give you a better idea. Also recheck the file path.

EDIT: 
Try passing the resource name only.

```
getClassLoader().getResource("names.txt");
```

Comment: the detailed message states:
/resources/names.txt (No such file or directory)
but that is not the path I provide. I provide: resources/names.txt

Comment: where is the resources folder? in which directory? Its assuming the resources folder is in the root.

Comment: the resources folder is in the root of the module. I dont know why it trys to load it from the filesystem root

Comment: try passing ./resources/names.txt (relative to current dir)

Comment: I've tried using resources. 
The problem is that it edits the filepath from "resources/names.txt" to "/resources/names.txt" and I dont understand why it does that

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but accepted answer didn't work for me.

Build System : Gradle

Working environment : Android Studio

I also included resources from external jar. But in order to use them I had to include full path also.

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/template/login.xml")
```

Hope this helps someone and prevents him from spending 3 hours banging his head against the wall to find an answer.