# Packaging files in an android application (but not in res or assets)

Tags: android, ssl, https, io, bouncycastle

Ok, So I've been thrown in a trench and would like to get out in the cleanest most respectable way possible.

At the moment I have 2 Android projects and am in a position where I need to package a file in one project and have it be sucessfully read by another. This can be confusing so let me explain.

I have 2 Android Projects. An android Library project named Engine and the application itself.

The Engine handles network communication and a number of other background tasks which oeprate headlessly and don't interact with the UI. The Engine has access to the main application's Context but nothing else. During my journey of developing this engine I came across something interesting. Https (don't run away) and the problems it presents in android applications. There have been many a blog post about how android applications are horrifically unsecure and are highly susceptible to MITM attacks. This is a problem I cannot ignore in this engine as it is a very real threat.

*For more reading on this I highly recommend Nikolay Elenkov's [blog](http://nelenkov.blogspot.ie/2011/12/using-custom-certificate-trust-store-on.html) as he explains great ways to do security right on Android!*

I digress though as this problem has already been solved. The solution for me was to use a custom keystore which is stored in a .bks file. Again you do not need to worry about how this was created or how it will be created. The real trouble is, how do I read this file when it is packaged inside a JAR.

For the final release, the Engine will be packaged as a jar and included in the application.
The caveat to this packaging of the engine into a jar is that anything in the res folder will not be compiled and cannot be read. By definition, any assets in the library project will not be reacahble whether the project is a jar or a library project.

So to recap we have 2 Projects. One Packaged Jar Android library which contains our BKS file and one application which needs to read it.

The BKS file cannot be recoved if it sites inside the assets/ or res/ folders.

Has anyone any ideas how to access this file?

Potential solutions:

- Store the file in lib directory and read it?
- Store the BKS on a remote server and load it in during startup?
- Find another way to deal with ssl certificates (And no I wont just accept any and all certificates!)
- Theres a super secret way to read files in android library projects in another folder, heres how you do it ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So to recap we have 2 applications

No, you don't.

> One Packaged Jar Android library which contains our BKS file and one application which needs to read it.

Which is one application, not two. You have two *projects*, but one *application*, based upon your description.

> Has anyone any ideas how to access this file?

Put the file in the application's project, whether that is `assets/` or `res/raw/` is up to you. If, from a source code control standpoint, you want the file to reside in the library project's repo, use a symlink or hardlink in the application project, or use commit hooks, or something to make a copy in the application project's location.

Or, package the file in the library JAR yourself and [use `getResourceAtStream()` to read it in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7180704/115145). I have not tried this, but presumably it works.

Comment: I meant to use the word projects and not applications in the recap. Updated. 

The main issue I was having was that Android seems to block the loading of resources when a library is packaged in a JAR. However this is with the use of resources identifiers like R.id.whatever.

Based on your answer, I should be able to read the file by specifying the location manually [InputStream i = new InputStream ....getResourceAsSteam.... ("absolute_path_to_res/raw")]. Have I understood you correctly?

Comment: @OVERTONE: That will only work if *you* arrange to put your file in the JAR. The JAR, by default, will only contain your compiled classes.

Comment: That is what I did. I altered my build.xml file to update the packaged application with the file in question. 

Then I accessedit using input streams as your comment dictates.

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of is using a content provider. Implement a content provider in your engine where you have the BKS file. Don't bother about implementing insert(), delete() etc. Just have these functions with empty body. Implement your query function, with a managed cursor, and populate the cursor with the content of BKS file. From you application query this content provider.

I did similar thing to exchange preferences between two applications.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = null;
   String[] columns = new String[] { "mycolumn"};
   Context otherAppsContext = null;
   try {
       otherAppsContext = mContext.createPackageContext("com.blah.blah", Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
   } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
   }
   prefs = otherAppsContext.getSharedPreferences("com.blah.blah_preferences_public",Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE|Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
   isConfigured = prefs.getBoolean("mycolumn", false);
   Object[]values = new Object[] {isConfigured==true?1:0};
   Log.d(TAG,"isConfigured " + isConfigured);
   MatrixCursor c = new MatrixCursor(columns);
   c.addRow(values);
   return c;
```

Comment: This is actually not a bad way to think about it as it is external storage in an android applciaiton. The part that gets me is this: 
"Implement your query function, with a managed cursor, and populate the cursor with the content of BKS file." That might not be possible because in order to do this, the bks file will need to be accesible when the engine starts. Bare in mind that the engine has no context of its own due to it being headless.

Before I make an attempt at this, are you sure that it is possible to access the create the bks file in a content provider without a context of the engine?

Comment: well, it worked for me to read a preference and store it in matrix cursor, and I used the context of the calling application, it your case too, the calling application should have the context. Isn't it?

Comment: The calling application has a context and the engine has access the same context. You follow? The Engine has no context of its own, it simply uses the applications context.

Comment: From what you've explained, the engine would store the file. It would need its own context to store inside a content provider and also it would need to have some initial access to the file.